# Packaging with all dependencies/devDependencies removed from package.json - why does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, package.json, quasar-framework

I am developing an Electron app using `Quasar framework`.

Due to restrictions, my `node_modules` are **static** (not allowed to download anything online and have a fixed node_modules locally - just copy paste in new project if the need arises). I never run `npm init`.

So in an attempt to minimize the bundled application size, I did an experiment and removed all `dependencies` and `devDependencies` from my `package.json`.

- I ran the app and it still works.
- But what surprised me is when I packaged the app, it still works. I do not get any errors stating that the required node_modules are missing.

How come? Could this be of `webpack`, `babel` or something that has been bundled on the Quasar framework?  Maybe the imported commands were compiled with the code and don’t need them to be included anymore as separate node_modules (ie in `dist/electron/AppName/resources`)?

This is good news for me. But just wanted to understand why and if this will cause grave errors/crashes whatsoever.

Thanks!

Comment: dependencies and devDependencies in package.json affect which packages are installed to node_modules with `npm install`. Seems like you already have everything you need in node_modules. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: @EstusFlask Does node/packagers not use the dependencies listed in package.json when creating the package for distribution (.exe)?

Comment: Some tool can possibly use these entries from package.json, although I'm unaware of such case. In your case they obviously aren't used. If the app runs, it's workable. You didn't specify details on how you build the app but if node_modules is included in your Electron app distribution, make sure no dev dependencies like Webpack are there because they would surely contribute to the size.